# I will always be you

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> Steal my prefix and I am you.
>
> Steal my suffix and I am you.
>
> Steal my infix and I am you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Are you a MEME

Steal my prefix and I am you.

> Meme - me is me.

Steal my suffix and I am you.

> Meme - me is me

Steal my infix and I am you.

> Meme - em is me

Comment: First of all, clever! Second of all, I think I'm missing something. How is "em" me? 'Em can mean "them," but that's neither "me" nor "you" (since it's not referring either to the speaker or the person being spoken to), is it? Or maybe "em" has a meaning I don't know?

Comment: I assume it's "meme minus me". I.e. remove the infix `em` from `meme` and get `me`.

Answer (score 15):

Alternative Answer

Smartest1here's answer uses the fact that each "you" refers to the same person.
Instead, it could be that each "you" refers to a different set of people.

So the answer could be

> Theme

Steal my prefix and I am you.

> Me

Steal my suffix and I am you.

> Them

Steal my infix and I am you.

> Thee (meaning "you").

Title

> "I will always be you" indicates that there is a *theme* going on here.